# Two ways to invoke a method

Tags: python, class

When I was learning the Object Oriented Programming, I found two ways of pulling a method in a class. And I wonder which one is better.

Let me create a very simple dog class as an example:

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def name_change(self, new_name):
        self.name = new_name

    def sit(self):
        print(self.name + ' is sitting')

my_dog = Dog('Jackie')
print('Dog name is ' + my_dog.name)

my_dog.name_change('Aaron')
print('Dog name is ' + my_dog.name)

Dog.name_change(my_dog, 'James')
print('Dog name is ' + my_dog.name)

my_dog.sit()
Dog.sit(my_dog)
```

You can see that I could use both to change an attribute:

```
my_dog.name_change('Aaron') 
Dog.name_change(my_dog, 'James')
```

I could also use both to pull the method for my_dog:

```
my_dog.sit()
Dog.sit(my_dog)
```

As a beginner, what I saw from the textbook, is usually the first way.

But somehow I kind of feel that the second way is easier for me to understand, because it starts with the class name, and narrow down to the class method, then use my instance(my_dog) as the self, then use other arguments when needed. It just feels very organized.

- So if guys can tell me if there is good and bad for both ways? Is it
  because it looks simpler?
- Or it really doesn't matter, I can use any way I want?
- Or is it that nobody is doing the second way, so don't do it?

Comment: The first way is standard, the second way is not equivalent. Part of the point of polymorphism is that you don't need to know the precise type of the object whose method you are calling. Imagine what would happen if you added a subclass of Dog, say `Hound`. Now every time you ask a dog to sit you have to figure out exactly what kind it is in advance, which sort of defeats one of the key benefits of OOP.

Comment: Suppose you have Dog and Cat classes with similar interfaces, and an object `mittens` which you don't know the type of. `mittens.name_change("Xerxes")` works regardless, but how are you going to do it the second way? `(Cat if isinstance(mittens, Cat) else Dog).name_change(mittens, "Xerxes")`? Seems like a mouthful.

Comment: @Kevin not much less of a mouthful using `type(mittens)` either :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I got the points. When I am facing the real world programming, there could be so many similar classes to work on. The first way gives me quickly editing without finding out everything that probably I don't have to know ahead. While the second way gives me a clear structural sense, I may not need it after I got very familar with coding.

Comment: @Kevin Your program just wouldn't compile if you named a dog 'mittens'. Or at least, it shouldn't.

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 the key thing to understand is the second way does something very different. It's also a bit of a pythonism (although put there in part for educational purposes) so it's important to understand what it is and why you _can_ do that but equally important to not actually write it.

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 you also need to think about inheritance... If you have a `Dog` and a `bark` function that returns `woof` and then you subclass it `class SpecialDog(Dog): def bark(self) return 'special!'` then create an instance of it, `sd = SpecialDog()` then call `sd.bark()` you get the correct behaviour... if however, you do (by mistake) `Dog.bark(sd)` you'll get `woof` instead and that's not what you intended...

Comment: @JonClements Yes, pvg mentioned it before. The second way seems to be more accurate, but that would cost me taking time to figure out the information that is not needed to know (figure out 'sd' the a regular dog or a special dog).

Comment: The second way is less accurate in a sense as it's depending on you the programmer to keep track of things... that's what the language is for... you just want to be able to call bark and have it call the correct bark for you... Basically behind the scenes when you use the first way, Python translates it to the second way but with the correct type automatically... So you're doing exactly the same thing, but it's less error prone when you let the language do it...

Comment: @JonClements  You are right, I agree with you on that. It should not be the programmer to keep track of things, it should be the language. Thank you sir, have a good day!

Comment: I didn't say it was more accurate. In fact, it's almost always wrong - it's an end-run around a key purpose of OOP which is why you're using a class in the first place.

Comment: @pvg by 'accurate' I mean, easier for me to understand and keep track of. But I do understand now, that it should not be my job to keep track of things. So your points are well taken! Thank you!